# Perfect Width To Fit Div Exactly

Tags: html, css, layout, padding, percentage

I have boxes floated inside a div sort of like the SO Chat except i am making a box for my own website where users can make their own chat room, these boxes on the page represent chatrooms and i want to make a perfect width for them so they will fit exactly on the page without any excess space in the margins. the main div they are positioned in is 965px with a padding of 15px on the left and right side of it making a 935px width i reduced the width from 965px to 935px to keep a total width of 965px.

To get an idea of my scenario check out A [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VbSau/)

As you can see there is some space left at the end right side of the div and i dont want that, i want the chat boxes to fit pixel perfectly the full width and remember to take into account that borders count as widths too. If someone could help me that would be great!

CSS Styles

```
body {
    width:1000px;
}

#Body {
    width:935px;
    padding:15px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#F1F1F1;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.ChatRoom {
    float:left;
    width:223px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:8.75px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
.ChatTitle {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#C6D6D9;
    border-bottom:2px solid #9C0;
}
```

Comment: space at the right of which div?

Comment: Should it say 'making a 995px width?'

Comment: no i wanted the centered div to be 965px so i added padding and it made it larger so i subtracted the total padding for the left and right side

Comment: This is why floats are not ideal in this kind of layout. Floats remove an element from the flow and position it as far left or right in the container as it will go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `box-sizing:border-box`. What it does is includes the `padding` and `border` sizes from the width, as opposed to its normal behaviour of adding to it (which makes the `<div>` overflow to the next line). I've added a `div.Inner` here which will have the border and white background while the `.ChatRoom` is used to provide space using `padding`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J86HN/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="ChatRoom">
    <div class="Inner">
        <div class="ChatTitle">My Chat Room</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ChatRoom {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:200px;
    padding:8px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.ChatRoom .Inner {
    border:1px solid #666;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:100%;
}
```

### Without `border-box`

Turns out it's pretty easy without `border-box` too, utilising `margin` on `.Inner`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaZSP/)

```
.ChatRoom {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:200px;
}
.ChatRoom .Inner {
    border:1px solid #666;
    margin:8px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: box-sizing isnt supported in ie8 and other browsers is there any other  options? thanks for the answer!

Comment: Updated, perhaps easier without `border-box` :P

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/DyTT8/1/

The last div needs to have the margin reset if not it will  add to the 15px of padding. I did this by giving it `class="last` and making the `.ChatRoom` div 225px; This will give you the proper spacing.

You could also put the divs in an unordered list and target the last div with li:last-child and remove the margin that way.